# After upgrade to OSX Lion, cannot access NAS share

Tags: macos, file-management, osx-lion

I've just upgraded to Lion and now it seems I can't connect to my NAS. I hit ⌘-K then in the server address I type in `smb://files`, as I would usually do. It thinks for a bit, then shows up in Finder with a red dot next to it.

Trying to open it gives the error:

> The folder "Volume_4" can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents

I can view the files in Terminal without problem though!

```
Als-MacBook-Pro:Volume_4 al$ ls -lAeO@ /Volumes/Volume_4/
total 200
-rwx-wx-wx   1 al  staff  arch   15364  3 Apr 16:47 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwx@  3 al  staff  -      16384 25 Oct  2009 .TemporaryItems
    com.apple.FinderInfo       32 
d---------   5 al  staff  -      16384 24 Dec  2009 .Trash-999
-rwxrwxrwx   1 al  staff  hidden  4096 25 Oct  2009 ._.TemporaryItems
d---------   2 al  staff  -      16384 13 Oct  2000 .systemfile
drwxrwxrwx  20 al  staff  -      16384 22 Jul  2010 files
drwxrwxrwx   5 al  staff  -      16384 16 Sep  2010 multimedia
```

I can also view and edit files from there.

Why can't I browse with Finder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Apple have made changes to the way file shares (both SMB and AFS) are accessed, I guess to improve security.

Various workarounds can be found here: http://frankleng.me/2011/07/21/connect-to-a-freenas-samba-or-afp-share-on-lion-workaround/

I managed to fix the problem by updating the firmware on my NAS (I'm using an Acer EasyStore).